# make-symbol creates a symbol with a sharpsign, getf fails in accessing it

Tags: common-lisp

I create a plist with keys that I turn into a symbol from some data with `make-symbol`:

```
(defparameter *plist* (list (make-symbol "key") "val"))
```

It creates the symbol `#:|key|`: it starts with a sharp sign.

```
(#:|key| "val")
```

Using `getf` mysteriously returns nil:

```
(getf *plist* :|key|)
NIL
```

and it is not possible to use `#:|key|`. This denotes, AFAIK, a variable, which is undefined. I tried a combination of `(intern (string (make-symbol…` with no success.

Note that the `access` library works on that structure:

```
(access:access *plist* :|key|)
"val"
T
```

What is going on? Is `make-symbol` appropriate? How can I make `getf` work?

Thanks

---

What I am doing is populating an existing plist with user data. New keys can be created on the fly. A plist has been convenient so far. Maybe is there a better suited data structure for this, like a hash-table.

Comment: @sds okay-ish to mark as duplicate… there would still be `:|key|` vs `'key` and `make-symbol` vs `read-from-string` and `getf` vs `access` to discuss, IMO.

Comment: So please ask a specific question that is not clear yet.

Comment: access compares symbol names (it defines its own equalper, used as a default test)

Comment: `(eq (intern "key" "KEYWORD") :|key|)`  -> T

Comment: Generally it's that useful to use an uninterned symbol like `#:|key|` as a key in a property list, since GETF does not support to choose an equality predicate. One would use a replacement for GETF with that feature, then.

Comment: `#:|foo|` donates an uninterned symbol with a case specific name "foo".

Comment: Thank you all for the tips nonetheless.